# Woocommerce product archive displays nothing when called from custom Page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-theming

I have a woocommerce shop page which shows me all of the products perfectly. This page is also set as the "Shop" page in the settings. Now I want a second page called Home, which should use the same template as the shop page. (basically a second shop page without categories and some news)

```
home-template.php

<?php /* Template Name: Homepage */ 
    if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
        exit; // Exit if accessed directly
    }
    wc_get_template( 'archive-product.php' );
?>
```

I'm using the standard archive-product template from woocommerce's github.

I can see the template being loaded, like the header, but certain woocommerce functions don't return the expected value. woocommerce_before_shop_loop doesn't return anything, even though it should display the orderby dropdown. woocommerce_product_loop() returns true, but wc_get_loop_prop('total') returns zero.

I've also tried renaming the file to front-page.php but that didn't help. The home page is set correctly in the reading settings.

Am i missing a call to a query, or is it something else? Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

When WooCommerce creates the builtin shop page it saves the id of the created page in the wp_options database table with option_name 'woocommerce_shop_page_id'. When WordPress loads a page WooCommerce checks if the page id of the page being loaded is equal to the option_value of option_name 'woocommerce_shop_page_id' and then executes code to generate the HTML of the shop page. If you have looked at the shop page in the page editor you will notice that the content is empty. The magic is being done with hard coded routines that execute for this special id.

Since, your custom page has a different page id none of the custom code for generating the shop page will be execute. So, you need to execute this magic code for your custom page. It can be done but you need a good understanding of WooCommerce.

I suggest you reconsider your design and instead of a new page just customize the existing shop page using actions and filters.